# implement strcat() function in C

Tags: c, string, strcat

I'm trying to implement strcat() in C but stuck on that the output result is repeated src.

here is my code.

```
void my_strcat(char des[], char src[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (des[i] != '\0')
        i += 1;
    while (src[j] != '\0') {
        des[i + j] = src[j];
        j += 1;
    }
    des[i + j] = '\0';

    printf("%s", des);
}

int main() {
   char des[1000], src[100];
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        printf("src: ");
        scanf("%s", src);
        my_strcat(des, src);
    }
    
    printf("%s", des);

}
```

the output is not the same as I was expected before. It's like for example:

src: a
src: b
des: aabb

Comment: `my_strcat` doesn't return anything, yet ou use its return value here: `printf("%s", my_strcat(des, src))`. Didn't you get at least c compiler warning?

Comment: @Jabberwocky is was my typo! I just want to use void type.

Comment: You have to initialitze des. `des[0]='\0';`

Comment: Then you probably want `printf("%s", des)`.

Comment: @Holger I added but it still does not work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah. I just want to print it out  not return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void my_strcat(char des[], const char src[]) {   // better use const her
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (des[i] != '\0')
    i += 1;
  while (src[j] != '\0') {
    des[i + j] = src[j];
    j += 1;
  }
  des[i + j] = '\0';

  // printf("%s", des);  // dont print des here
}

int main() {
  char des[1000];
  char src[100];
  des[0] = 0;   // initialize des to a zero length string      
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    printf("src: ");
    scanf("%s", src);
    my_strcat(des, src);
  }

  printf("%s", des);   // print the destination
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. But please Could you explain why using printf() inside my_strcat() is not working?

Comment: @KeinKeinKein it _is_ working, but it should not be there. After all your function is called `my_strcat` and not `my_strcat_and_print_result`

Comment: @KeinKeinKein The only relevant line is `des[0] = 0;`. When you initialize the destination, your example will work with or without the `printf()` call.